# Connection Accepts on Localhost Refuses on IP IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

I am trying to access my IIS website via the servers IP address from my local PC.

The server has a fixed IP and is a fresh installation of Windows Server 2016 on a VM.
On the server - When I open my browser and load http://localhost the website loads fine. 
When I access the website via the IP http://129.232.xxx.xxx then the connection is refused. (The request is refused even if I try to access http://129.232.xxx.xxx from the server).

A lot of sites (from google search) wants to see the bindings in my site, I have included them below:
[image: Bindings]

I have also made sure that the ports are allowed in my firewall:
[image: Allow Rule]
[image: Ports Allowed]

From wireshark I can see that the request is received by the server, but I have no idea why it resets (I'm new to wireshark so I also don't understand how to read all this information yet).

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

All I want to know what I am missing and where I should start looking for the problem?

Comment: FYI your IP is visible in the Wireshark filter

Comment: Tx @Lenniey I didn't notice, I fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted my younger brother and he told me the following:

Open Command Prompt and enter `netstat -a`
From there we noticed that the server was listening on port 80 and 443

However it was listening on IP 127.0.0.1.
[It's impossible for both servers to listen on the same port at the same IP address: since a single socket can only be opened by a single process, only the first server configured for a certain IP/port combination will successfully bind, and the second one will fail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108387/apache-and-iis-side-by-side-both-listening-to-port-80-on-windows2003)

So we changed the IP it was listening to by entering the following commands in Command Prompt. (Make sure you start cmd with admin privileges)
[Source 2](https://forums.iis.net/t/1223366.aspx)

Enter the following commands:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

press enter, then enter

```
netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Restarted the server and everything worked perfectly

Note that your server will now listen all incoming traffic 
Make sure that you refine your firewall rules to block unwanted traffic and ports. He recommended using https://www.pcsp.co.za/.

Once you have closed the port you can do a port scan from https://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/ to determine which ports are still open.